# pytest-django: how to change PASSWORD_HASHERS

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I want to use a weaker password hashing algorithm when testing for less time consuming. According to [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/#password-hashing) and this article [article](https://dizballanze.com/django-blazing-fast-tests/), I add below code inside `settings.py`

```
import sys

if 'test' in sys.argv:
    PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    ]
```

when I run
`python3.7 manage.py test` the tests run very fast, but if I run `pytest` it just cost the same time as before, what should I do?

Comment: isn't it better to have a `test_settings.py` specifically for your tests? then you can run `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=test_settings` before your tests and all settings will be ready for you.

Comment: What exactly are you testing, is login part relevant for your tests or you just need logged in user?